# How to prevent XSS for the form action URL?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-site, zap

We use Shibboleth's SingleSingOut(SSO) to do the authentication.Shibboleth is an open-source project which has been integrated into our project. Shibboleth will do the redirect to login.jsp page, if the user has not been authenticated.Now we have customized login.jsp page to support localization. So, the form actionUrl has to be sent by the Shibboleth IDP(Identity Provider) to perform the authentication. Here is the below sample code which the Shibboleth has provided:

```
    <% if(request.getAttribute("actionUrl") != null){ %>
      <form id="login" action="<%=request.getAttribute("actionUrl")%>" method="post">
    <% }else{ %>
      <form id="login" action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <% } %>

      <% if ("true".equals(request.getAttribute("loginFailed"))) { %>
        <section>
          <p class="form-element form-error">Login has failed. Double-check your username and password.</p>
        </section>
      <% } %>

      <legend>
        Log in to <idpui:serviceName/>
      </legend>

      <section>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-element form-field" name="j_username" type="text" value="">
      </section>

      <section>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-element form-field" name="j_password" type="password" value="">
      </section>

      <section>
        <button class="form-element form-button" type="submit">Login</button>
      </section>
    </form>
```

Now I have used the OWASP ZAP tool to check the security attack. It has raised a High Risk at the below code

```
  <form id="login" action="<%=request.getAttribute("actionUrl")%>" method="post">
```

It has told that there can be XSS (Cross-site Scripting) attack so, it has asked me to encode the above code.

How can I prevent the XSS(Cross Site Scripting) for the form action url. Because, it is an untrusted data is there any way to encode the URL. After some research I found that, its better to use ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL('url'); method. My doubt is that, is it a correct way to use the ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL('url') for the form action URL?

From the [Cross_Site_Scripting Prevention Cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Actual form action url:

```
     <form name="loginForm" id="login" method="POST" action="<%=request.getParameter("actionUrl")%>">
```

Encoded form action url:

```
     <form name="loginForm" id="login" method="POST" action="<%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL(request.getParameter("actionUrl"))%>">
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to prevent XSS like you write in the title, or do you want to prevent the escaping of the `action` url? What is your problem with using `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL`? Why do you add `<pre>` around your `form`?

Comment: I have edited the above comments. I would like to prevent the XSS for the form action URL . My doubt is that, can I use the `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL()` for the form action URL because when I saw the Rule #5 from [Cross_Site_Scripting Prevention Cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), it has mentioned that this rule has to be applied for HTML URL Parameter Values.

Comment: You always need to escape data you originally got from an untrusted source, no matter where you insert it into your page. As `actionUrl` might be something like `"  onsubmit="alert('xss');` you need to escape `actionUrl` so that it won't allow this kind of attack. But then there is still another problem, as someone could pass `http://a-malicious-domain.com/to/collect/data` as `actionUrl`, and then the form data would be send to a foreign domain. Just escaping the url would not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL()` is not correct because this does percent encoding of the whole string which can corrupt the url. It's meant more for encoding individual parameters within a url.

In this context, within an attribute, `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute()` should be used.

There is an extra problem here though. If the url is not trusted, then the user could be sending their log in details to an untrusted site. You should check exactly where the url comes from and make sure the user can't control its contents.

If the url is always of a similar format, then you can check against this in the controller.

Comment: Thank you fgb. After using this encodeForHTMLAttribute() for the form action url, How can I test whether it is encoding the URl?.
 - Will there be any difference to the form action url after using the encodeForHTMLAttribute(), when I check through the developer console of chrome browser?

Comment: @SarathUpadrista There won't be any difference unless the url contains characters it shouldn't, like quotes. Because of how the url is used, it needs to be trusted, so encoding isn't the main concern. It's making sure that a user can't change the url which should hopefully already be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fundamentally flawed if you are using user input for the form action.

What is the bigger picture of your code? We can help you design it better so that you are not using user input as a form action to start with

Comment: Hello Born, Please check my complete code. I have edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

you should use tools like "modsecurity" which uses "regular expression" and has some rules to prevent xss attacks.
Take a look at :

http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/08/securing-apache-part-10-mod_security/
http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2013/09/modsecurity-xss-evasion-challenge-results.html

I hope they make sense ...